# C# Update + with "label"

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to change this

```
string query = "Update tbPegawai set Total_Gaji = Total_Gaji +   where Kode_Pegawai = " + textBoxKDPegawai.Text + "";
```

to this:

```
string query = "Update tbPegawai set Total_Gaji = Total_Gaji + "**Label**"  where Kode_Pegawai = " + textBoxKDPegawai.Text + "";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: And where is your problem? What exactly is `Label`? Is it a variable?

Comment: Please read the [help] and in particular [ask]. If you don't show any effort in trying to solve your problem you will receive a lot of downvotes. As second advice. Learn how to use parameters. That code is a disaster waiting to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
string query = string.Format(@"Update tbPegawai set Total_Gaji = Total_Gaji + ""{0}""  where Kode_Pegawai = ""{1}""",Label.Text,textBoxKDPegawai.Text);
```

Comment: Nice... Thanks Yousuf :)

Answer (score 0):

string query = "Update tbPegawai set Total_Gaji = Total_Gaji + \"Label\" where Kode_Pegawai = " + textBoxKDPegawai.Text + "";

or

string query = @"Update tbPegawai set Total_Gaji = Total_Gaji + "Label" where Kode_Pegawai = " + textBoxKDPegawai.Text + "";